# Error uploading update to ubuntu touch app: app version is not different from the earlier one

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

This refers to an app I have published (recorder). I wanted to update to a newer version but I get an error saying that the new version is not newer than the version already published.

What does this mean? The version number is different and so is the app.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: app is published on myapps.developer.ubuntu.com

Comment: You can edit you question instead of writing comment, if you missed something.

Answer (score 1):

apparently the problem is that the version you're trying to upload is somehow "lower" than the one already in the system. You should be able to upload version 0.30 (for example) though.